# RegEx to extract certain lines in file and remove certain lines starting with str

Tags: regex, markdown, regex-negation

I have the following code.

```
r"""file description line one.

Further explanation 1.
Further explanation 2.

TODO: refactor 1.
TODO: refactor 2.

Further explanation 3. 
"""

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
...
```

I want to ask for a single regular expression to return the following code:

```
r"""file description line one.

Further explanation 1.
Further explanation 2.


Further explanation 3. 
"""
```

That is, returns the file description only, but removes lines starting with `TODO`.

Thanks!

---

Do you want to catch the words after comment?

No

---

Currently I could find this workaround: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uCYycf/1). It does not match `Further explanation 3.` (though I wanted to match it). It does not match `r"""` but it's OK.

---

**I found one solution myself. Please see below (one of the answers).**

Comment: ^((?!TODO).).*$
Do you want to catch the words after comment??

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question. Using http://regex101.com (set to Python flavor) you can play around with regular expressions.

Comment: is the 'r' at the beginning a mistake? Or do you actually want to keep it?

Comment: The 'r' is fine.  It means a "raw" string, which means that backslashes are taken literally.  Since the text doesn't contain any backslashes, the 'r' is superfluous, but ok.

Comment: @Moid - isn't your expression going to strip the empty lines?  What is the purpose of the outer pair of parens?

Comment: @CryptoFool. Using the outer pair to generate lines. if we don't use outer pair, it doesn't capture empty lines.

Comment: @Moid - I don't see how that's true.  '.' does not match EOLs in this context.  The second '.' is going to match 'f', 'F', 'F' and 'F'.

Comment: ooops....slight correction.  It is the FIRST '.' that is going to need to match a character to accept a line.  The outer parens don't affect what is matched, but only what is captured, and in this case, they capture the first char of the line, which I don't see as being valuable.

Comment: @Moid Thanks! I tried your query but the empty line is not kept: https://regex101.com/r/cndpmJ/1. Back to you question: No I don't want to catch words after comments.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly This is not a XY problem - I need to use RegEx to do so :(

Comment: @Moid Oops, I just saw your answer below, yes `^(?!TODO|import).*$` captures empty line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find one solution: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/16aAR2/4).

Basically I have two parts: `^(?!TODO).*$(?=[\S\s]*^\"\"\"$)`|`^\"\"\"$`.

Second part (`^\"\"\"$`) is trivial.

`^(?!TODO).*$`, I tried to match all the lines that not start with `TODO` (negative lookahead).

`(?=[\S\s]*^\"\"\"$)` is another lookahead but positively. It tries to examine if there is a single line `"""` (`^\"\"\"$`) after possibly lines later`[\S\s]*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^(?!TODO|import).*$"

test_str = ("r\"\"\"file description line one.\n\n"
    "Further explanation 1.\n"
    "Further explanation 2.\n\n"
    "TODO: refactor 1.\n"
    "TODO: refactor 1.\n\n"
    "Further explanation 3. \n"
    "\"\"\"\n\n"
    "import numpy as np\n"
    "import pandas as pd\n"
    "...")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

If you just want TODOS to remove, remove import from regex line.
Change regex to `regex = r"^((?!TODO).).*$"`

Comment: If you want to retain the blank lines, you need `"^(?!TODO|import).*$"`. '.' does not match EOLs, so your version needs to match at least one regular character on the line.  - to be safe, I ran your code.  It does not report blank lines.

Comment: I believe the OP want to extract the docstring without TODOs from a full text file and the `...` at the end are there just to indicate the file has more lines, which may not start with `import`. Maybe they start with `df = pd.DataFrame(...`. And they don't want _those_ lines either.

Comment: Still, is a good approach to apply after isolating the full docstring.

Comment: Thanks! However, I only want the contents in the comments. Then remove TODO's.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73348416/15032126), let's capture first the whole docstring and then all lines excluding the ones starting with "TODO"

```
import re

docstring_pattern = r'(?s)""".*?"""$'  # should work the same with r'"""[\s\S]*?"""$'
pattern_TODOs = r'^(?!TODO).*\s'
test_str = '''
r"""file description line one.

Further explanation 1.
Further explanation 2.

TODO: refactor 1.
TODO: refactor 1.

Further explanation 3. 
"""

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
...
'''

doc = re.findall(docstring_pattern, test_str, re.MULTILINE)[0]

matches = re.findall(pattern_TODOs, doc+'\n', re.MULTILINE)
>>>print(''.join(list(matches)))

"""file description line one.

Further explanation 1.
Further explanation 2.


Further explanation 3. 
"""
```

The `\s` at the end of the second pattern is to capture the empty lines, that was one problem in the other answer.

`docstring_pattern` will capture the whole string in a single match. The `*?` inside the pattern ensures it captures only one docstring at a time (in case there were more than one in the whole code text) and only the first one is assigned to `doc`.

Comment: Hi Thanks! However, I do not want to write Python code (if so it'd be easier right). I want a single RegEx.